# Change UITabBar while running

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm making a theme for my app, and when I switch themes, the UITabBar doesn't want to apply coloration.

The bar only take the color defined in the active theme at launching.
I'm calling this but it doesn't work :/

```
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarStyle:[theme tabBarStyle]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearance proxy has no effect on existing views - only on future views. That is why it is usually called only at launch time, before there is any interface at all.

You are free to set the appearance proxy at any time, but if you want existing views to change their appearance you must do that in the normal way, i.e. by sending a message directly to those existing views. You'll have organize your code in such a way as to make that possible.

Alternatively, of course, you can set the appearance proxy, destroy your entire existing interface, and then rebuild your interface under the influence of the new proxy settings.

Comment: Then, is it possible by another way ?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just set the actual tab bar's actual bar style!

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. That's why I used this code. How would you do this please ?

Comment: It does work. _What_ did you try and _what_ "didn't work"? That's meaningless.

Comment: I don't exactly remember what I did, but I tried again and it worked. I probably did something stupid --' (it was in the middle of the night ^^')
Then, thanks you :)
(I've to wait before accepting you answer ;) )